# ios9 SceneKit overlaySKScene

Tags: ios, ios9, scenekit, skscene

I've been developing a game using SceneKit framework and an overlaySKScene. The overlay contains a label and a few animatable sprites. Everything worked like a charm on iOS8.4. But after updating my device to iOS9, I don't see the overlay elements any more. SCNScene elements are okay, though something is wrong with the light (it has become much brighter).

I've already read about necessity of setting zPosition in iOS9 and tried that with no success.

I've also tried to copy my custom subclass of SKScene, used as the overlay, to the Bananas Apple test/example project. And there I could see the label and sprites. So, the problem must be in my SCNView or SCNScene definitions, rendering order or whatsoever. Any ideas what could be updated in the latest iOS release?

I would greatly appreciate any your assistance, as I am stuck now.

Comment: when is the overlay added to the scene? Does adding it after the view is fully configured (`awakeFromNib` on iOS, `viewDidMoveToWindow` on OS X) help?

Comment: I did set it in viewDidAppear after a delay, tried in viewDidLoad. Forgot to say, that it works in iOS9 simulators, but does not work on a device.

Comment: Strangely, I see this on OSX 10.11 as well, but only on a 2012 MBP, not on a retina iMac. And the Bananas sample works fine for me too. The only big difference in my case is that Bananas is Obj-C.

Comment: My app is also in Obj-C.

Comment: Try enabling camera controls, and then zooming your scene out really far. Or manually set your camera's zFar very low. When I do this, as soon as the camera starts culling scene geometry, my overlay scene comes into view again. Not a solution, but maybe a clue. You mentioned reading about overlays, zPosition and iOS 9. Can you paste a link to that?